# how to get bitmap data from jpg file on wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

is there any library which can help me with getting single pixels from JPG file loaded from Phone media library on WP7? I need to access to single pixels, but now I am only able to get whole file into byte array or access to these bytes through memory stream. Any ideas? I found FJcore but I can´t use it because of reflections...

Here is what I´ve got:

```
byte[] contents = new byte[e.ChosenPhoto.Length];
MemoryStream fullFileStream = new MemoryStream();
int bytes;
while ((bytes = e.ChosenPhoto.Read(contents, 0, contents.Length)) > 0)
{
    fullFileStream.Write(contents, 0, bytes);
}
```

And I need some library with method like *GetPixels()* to access to single pixels from loaded image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [WritableBitmap.Pixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Pixel manipulation in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 sometimes sufferers sluggish performance - consider using XNA.

Comment: sorry, I forgot mention that loaded pictures are really large (for example 10 000 x 10 000) so I can´t use WriteableBitmap because of it´s limitation of image maximum size about 2000 x 2000. I need to use memory stream and byte array to load that picture - and from that array I need to get single pixels.

Comment: Maybe there is something in XNA or Open Source project. Basically, you have made your custom image processor. Read a few kB of memory and process it.

Comment: But I don´t know how to work with that array of bytes where I have loaded large jpg image. I need to split this image into smaller pieces - because of that I need to find out width and height of the original image and get access to single pixels. Do you know some open source project or library which could help me? I have no clue :-(

Comment: I really need help please - I am searching something helpful for me and I can´t find anything for days!...

Comment: If you can't find anything, probably there is no such thing. Don't waste your time for searching, implement your own class. I suggest you to make another question where you describe the problem. Maybe this is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ includes a `GetPixel` method which sounds just like what you need.

**Update**
Based on the comments you've made to other answers, I think you need to conider a different approach. The 2000 pixel limit is a framework limitation designed to try and preserve performance by not including framework elements which are significantly larger than the screen size.

If your images are 10k x 10k pixels then you should seriously consider processing them off the device and then only loading smaller versions or subsections onto the actual device.

Comment: any hint for my reports I´ve added above?

Comment: But I am loading images from Phone´s media library and I need to process them on that device...